# Counting rows divided by conditions in one select

Tags: mysql, select, count

This is what  basically my mysql-table looks like:

```
id  | A  |  B  
-------------
1 | bla  |  1
2 | bla  |  2
3 | bla  |  1
4 | bla  |  1
5 | bla  |  2
6 | bla  |  2
7 | bla  |  1
```

I wanna count how many rows do have 1 as B value and how many rows do have 2 as B value. Is it possible/does it make sense to do this in one SELECT statement?

regards && tia
  noircc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use COUNT(*) and GROUP BY , that will give you your result.

```
SELECT B,count(*) as occurence from myTable group by B;
```